# Decrement by a deleted document value Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an expense tracker app where:

- **(Task completed)** The user can set a monthly budget (ie. $3,000) that is stored in a '--currentBudget--' document in a year-month collection.
- **(Task completed)** The user can add an expense through a form (title, amount, category, date) which is stored in a unique document in the year-month collection, the data is then aggregated in the '--totalSpent--' by total spending and categorized total spending.
- **(Not completed)** The user can delete an expense that would update the values in the '--totalSpent--'. How would I do this using Cloud Firestore? I'm thinking I could reference the document I'm deleting and decrement by the amount value to its respected year-month(date) record based on total spending and categorized total spending.

Firestore Console
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKTUg.jpg

```
/* ADD EXPENSE */
function addExpense(user) {
  // DOM Form Selectors
  const expenseForm = document.getElementById('expense-form');
  const expenseTitle = document.getElementById('expense-title');
  const expenseAmount = document.getElementById('expense-amount');
  const expenseCategory = document.getElementById('expense-category');
  const expenseDate = document.getElementById('expense-date');

  // Submit Event
  expenseForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Database Reference
    const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(expenseAmount.value);
    const expenseRef = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection(expenseDate.value).doc();
    const totalSpent = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection(expenseDate.value).doc('--totalSpent--');

    // Database Batch Write
    const batch = db.batch();

    // Creates Unqiue Expense Document
    batch.set(expenseRef, { title: expenseTitle.value, amount: expenseAmount.value, category: expenseCategory.value, date: expenseDate.value });

    // Updates totalSpending
    batch.set(totalSpent, { totalSpending: increment }, { merge: true });
    //Updates totalSpending by category
    batch.set(totalSpent, { [expenseCategory.value]: increment }, { merge: true });
    batch.commit();

    // Reset Form
    expenseForm.reset();
    modal[1].classList.add('hidden');
    overlay.classList.add('hidden');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfect fit for a [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) solution.

You can use the `onCreate` and `onDelete` event triggers to change the total value. With the usage of `transactions` you ensure a safe execution.

If the users can even change the values in existing expenses you could also use the `onUpdate` trigger to handle even those use cases.

Here is a basic example for your database and for the `onCreate` and `onDelete` triggers:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document("/users/{userUid}/{year_month}/{expenseUid}")
  .onCreate(async (eventSnapshot, context) => {
    const { userUid, expenseUid } = context.params;
    const expenseData = eventSnapshot.data();
    const { spending = 0 } = expenseData;

    try {
      await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t) => {
        const totalRef = admin
          .firestore()
          .doc("/users/{userUid}/{year_month}/--totalSpend--");
        const doc = await t.get(totalRef);

        const newTotalSpending = doc.data().totalSpending || 0 + spending;
        t.update(totalRef, { totalSpending: newTotalSpending });
      });

      console.log("Transaction success!");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Transaction failure:", e);
    }
  });

exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document("/users/{userUid}/{year_month}/{expenseUid}")
  .onDelete(async (eventSnapshot, context) => {
    const { userUid, expenseUid } = context.params;
    const expenseData = eventSnapshot.data();
    const { spending = 0 } = expenseData;

    try {
      await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t) => {
        const totalRef = admin
          .firestore()
          .doc("/users/{userUid}/{year_month}/--totalSpend--");
        const doc = await t.get(totalRef);

        const newTotalSpending = doc.data().totalSpending || 0 - spending;
        t.update(totalRef, { totalSpending: newTotalSpending });
      });

      console.log("Transaction success!");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Transaction failure:", e);
    }
  });
```

The main benefit of using the cloud functions is that you don't need to give your users the right to edit the `total` value and all changes are done automaticaly in teh backend.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the transactions as they keep failing, it is having trouble reading doc.data().totalSpending as it is undefined. It can't update the totalSpending. Before I was using a batch write which would create the '--totalSpent--' but it can't read using the transaction.

Comment: Still saying it's undefined

Comment: ```Transaction failure: TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalSpending' of undefined. ``` I also manually set values in the firestore database still undefined.